# Appium issue : java.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream Connection

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, appium, mobile-application, appium-ios

Not able to click elements on the application launched. Mobile Application gets downloaded and opens but no element gets clicked, no error on `appium` server.

Below are the versions used:

```
Simulator device - iPhone 8

Simulator Version 11.0 (SimulatorApp-912.1 SimulatorKit-570.3 CoreSimulator-681.5.1)

Java client version java-client-6.0.0-BETA4.jar

Appium Version 1.15.1 (1.15.1.20191013.2)

macOS Mojave version 10.14.5 (18F203)

X code Version 11.0 (11A420a)

java version "1.8.0_191"

selenium-java-3.141.59-sources.jar
```

Logs at the console:

```
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create a new remote session. Original error: unexpected end of stream on Connection{127.0.0.1:4723, proxy=DIRECT hostAddress=/127.0.0.1:4723 cipherSuite=none protocol=http/1.1}

Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'

System info: host: 'C02Z53KELVCF', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:4d1:face:6ad2:ee7a%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.14.5', java.version: '1.8.0_191'

Driver info: driver.version: IOSDriver

Driver info: driver.version: IOSDriver

  at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor$1.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:208)

  at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:217)

  at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:239)

  at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)

  at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:42)

  at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)

  at io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSDriver.execute(IOSDriver.java:1)

  at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:213)

  at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)

  at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.<init>(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:38)

  at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:84)

 at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:94)

  at io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSDriver.<init>(IOSDriver.java:95)

  at com.netspend.ns_tester.Selenium.DriverHandler.getLocalDriver(DriverHandler.groovy:193)

  ... 22 more

Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

  at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor$1.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:186)

  ... 35 more

Caused by: java.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream on Connection{127.0.0.1:4723, proxy=DIRECT hostAddress=/127.0.0.1:4723 cipherSuite=none protocol=http/1.1}

  at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1Codec.readResponseHeaders(Http1Codec.java:208)

  at okhttp3.internal.http.CallServerInterceptor.intercept(CallServerInterceptor.java:88)

  at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)

  at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)

  at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.OkHttpClient$Factory$1.lambda$createClient$1(OkHttpClient.java:152)

  at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)

  at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:45)

  at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)

  at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)

  at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)

 at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)

  at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)

  at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)

 at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)

  at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:126)

  at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)

  at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)

  at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:200)

  at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:77)

  at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.OkHttpClient.execute(OkHttpClient.java:103)

  at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:105)

  ... 36 more

Caused by: java.io.EOFException: \n not found: limit=0 content=…

  at okio.RealBufferedSource.readUtf8LineStrict(RealBufferedSource.java:237)

  at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1Codec.readHeaderLine(Http1Codec.java:215)

  at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1Codec.readResponseHeaders(Http1Codec.java:189)

  ... 56 more
```

Comment: paste your driver initialization code and the way you run appium server

Comment: Running Appium GUI , My app is getting launched in simulator but after that nothing happened.This is the error i can see in my appium logs-  [Xcode] 2019-12-16 17:39:29.692991+0530 WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner[68931:520926] Cannot request the screen point at NSPoint: {64, 64}: Error Domain=XCTDaemonErrorDomain Code=11 "No AXElement found at {64 64}: kAXErrorInvalidUIElement" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=No AXElement found at {64 64}: kAXErrorInvalidUIElement}

Comment: still no information about your driver initialization and no code provided.

Comment: if these caps are the only ones that you provided, then you need to read more attentively official [docs](http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/caps/) and provide **all** neccesary caps

Comment: DesiredCapabilities desiredCapabilities = new DesiredCapabilities(); desiredCapabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, 'iOS');
desiredCapabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, "12.2");
desiredCapabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "iPhone 8");
desiredCapabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME, "XCUITest");
desiredCapabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, "path to x.app");

URL url = new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub");

IOSDriver driver = new IOSDriver(url, desiredCapabilities);

Comment: @Vault23 i have updated the code

Comment: why you said that there is no error in appium logs when you have one `Caused by: java.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream on Connection{127.0.0.1:4723, proxy=DIRECT hostAddress=/127.0.0.1:4723 cipherSuite=none protocol=http/1.1}
` ? looks like you have problems with appium server initialization.

Comment: I am using same capacilites with different values for android, things are working fine but not with ios.  what other changes should i need to do for IOS?

Comment: again: you need to read official docs. you don't have `wdaLocalPort`, `xcodeOrgId` and `xcodeSigningId` caps at least. Your question should be closed